# Portable Apache web server for Linux

Tags: web-server, portable, apache

While looking for software components for a custom LAMP stack, I noticed MariaDB offers [pre-compiled binary tarballs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/installing-mariadb-binary-tarballs/), which you just untar in whatever folder you want.

However I wasn't able to find an "equivalent" for Apache web server, if it exists, in fact the site only has binaries for Windows.

Does it exist a pre-compiled binary tarball for Apache web server, without resorting to use complete LAMP stacks like XAMPP?

Comment: You could take a .DEB or .RPM and unpack it instead oft installing it. Although I don't think this is a good solution. Install Apache or use docker.

Answer (score 1):

You can find any number of virtual machines that include apache as an already all setup web server.  My knee-jerk server is scotchbox for instance..

Comment: My problem is not setting up the web server, but rather not depend on the OS repository version of it; I could compile it from source but I'd like to avoid the hassle.